# npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's ajv@6.12.6 does not satisfy ajv@8.11.0

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to deploy my React app in Heroku and I have this error in my terminal:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 16.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 16.17.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 8.15.0
remote:        
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
remote:        Module installation may take longer for this build
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        npm ERR! code EUSAGE
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's ajv@6.12.6 does not satisfy ajv@8.11.0
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @types/react@18.0.17 does not satisfy @types/react@17.0.48
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 does not satisfy json-schema-traverse@1.0.0
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
```

Comment: Did you _read_ the error? `\`npm ci\` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with \`npm install\` before continuing.`

Comment: Hello, i have already type this command but still have the error :(